# Hudson CI - Tagging every build

Tags: svn, hudson, tagging, hudson-plugins

I am looking for a plugin that will tag (subversion) every single build that Hudson makes ever.

I have found the Subversion tagging plugin but it replaces the tag every time a new build happens. I would like to keep track of every single build that goes through the system.

I would prefer a plugin since most of the hudson jobs involve multiple subversion locations i to would be a hassle trying to add tag post hooks.

Please and thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have been using the maven release plug-in for a while. Maven release plugin has a goal,

```
install release:prepare
```

which tags the codebase, if the build succeeds. I assume that you want to tag the code base rather than the artifact.

It does changes the version of the project from 1.1-SNAPSHOT to 1.1 and tags the codebase. So your development version will become 1.2.

Comment: could you explain the usage a bit more clearly with an example. does this work with multi module build over multiple subversion repositories?

Comment: It does work with projects having multiple modules tied together by a root pom. But I'm not sure about multiple repositories.

Answer (score 0):

I had to tackle the same problem and I have not found any plugin for that. Sadly, I had to do this "by hand".

Later it turned out that tagging every build wasn't necessary at all. Tagging the last successful build is very handy when you want to checkout the latest working source code. And if a build is important for some reason I just click "Keep this build" in Hudson, or "Tag this build".

Comment: Understood but, we release new version quite frequently and we need to automate this process. It need to be every single build needs to be tagged.

Comment: If that's the case then probably the only way to go is to write a new plugin by modifying the source of the successful build tagger plugin... Perhaps you just need to comment out one `if` clause, where the status of a build is being checked. :)

Comment: Excellent! Where is the source?